# Ubuntu heat problems with Medion Akoya Notebook

Tags: nvidia, wubi, overheating, hybrid-graphics

My Notebook heats up tremendously after I start Ubuntu - I also noticed that it runs slower than my Windows 7 (not to mention the fact, that Windows 7 does not come even close to the heat production of Ubuntu).

**The specifications of my notebook are**:

- Intel Dual Core i3, 2,6 Ghz
- Geforce GT540M (1 GB)
- 2 GB ddr-ram

I wonder if this could be because my notebook has onboard graphics and a graphics card (hybrid graphics) and ubuntu doesnt know which one to use?

I am really kind of desperate because I dont know if my notebook is crap or I just have wrong adjustments to my laptop (I am running Ubuntu via Wubi btw as I am new to Linux) - but I really want to make the change and stop using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the temperature too much. If your cpu is between 45/65º C and your gpu is between 70/80º C everything is OK (it's not the best temperature but it's OK).

Install your nvidia graphics driver from the official site or install envy (envy will make it automatically). You can install xsensors to follow your cpu temp and your intel gpu temp.

For the nvidia gpu temp you have the sensors from the nvidia driver.
You can install indicator-cpufreq package for intel speed step control and get your cpu frequency lower. It will reduce the heat(I'm using it).

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

**PS:** if you have ubuntu 12.04 dist-upgrade to 13.04. You will gain better performance and less resources usage.